# Limit of integral of $L^p$ functions

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $p\in (0,\infty)$ and $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$. 
Show that $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x) \chi_{[-n,n]}\frac{1}{n^{(1-1/p)}} dx=0$.

I believe $f(x) \chi_{[-n,n]}\frac{1}{n^{(1-1/p)}}\to 0$ a.e., and using Holder's inequality, I have

$\displaystyle \int \left|f(x) \chi_{[-n,n]}\frac{1}{n^{1-1/p}}\right| dx\leq \|f\|_p \left(\int_{-n}^n \frac{1}{n^{q(1-1/p)}} dx\right)^{1/q}=\|f\|_p 2^{1/q}$.

I either need a dominating function/sequence of functions for $f(x) \chi_{[-n,n]}\frac{1}{n^{(1-1/p)}}$ or a decreasing sequence, which dominates $\int f(x) \chi_{[-n,n]}\frac{1}{n^{(1-1/p)}} dx$, but I'm not sure how to get either.

Answer (score 1):

This is a special case of  [Does scaling lead to weak convergence to the null function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/805982/) (in the notation of that post, use $f=\chi_{[-1,1]}$). But since your question does not use the language of weak convergence, I give an answer without it. The idea is any $L^p$ function (for $p<\infty$) is somewhat localized. Namely, for every $\epsilon$ there exists $M$ such that 
$$\int_{|x|>M} |f|^p<\epsilon$$
When we integrate $f$ against $g_n=\chi_{[-n,n]}\frac{1}{n^{(1-1/p)}}$ with $n$ much larger than $M$, most of the $L^q$ norm of $g_n$ is "wasted", being  matched against the thin tail of $f$. Formally: 
$$\left|\int_{|x|>M}  f  g_n\right|\le 2^{1/q}\epsilon^{1/p} $$
and 
$$\left|\int_{|x|\le M}  f  g_n\right|\le \frac{2M}{n}\|f\|_p  $$
both by Hölder's inequality.