# Weak convergence, $\displaystyle f\in L^p(\Bbb R^d) $ and $g\in L^q(\Bbb R^d) $ then, $\lim_{j\to\infty} \int_{\Bbb R^d}f_j(x)g(x)dx = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, weak-convergence

Assume $f\in L^p(\Bbb R^d) $ and  $g\in L^q(\Bbb R^d) $
Where, $1<p<\infty$ and $1<q<\infty$ are dual ecxponents namely, $$\frac1p+\frac1q =1$$
Then for every $s\in\Bbb R$ such that, $sp\le d$ show that,
$$\lim_{j\to\infty} \int_{\Bbb R^d}f_j(\mathbf{x})g(\mathbf{x})\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x} = 0$$

Where, $$f_j(\mathbf{x}) = j^sf(j\mathbf{x})~~~$$

**My attempt,**

I Applied Holder inequality, and use the change of variables $\mathbf{u} =j\mathbf{x}$ to get the following,

\begin{align}\left|\int_{\Bbb R^d}f_j(\mathbf{x})g(\mathbf{x})\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}\right| &\le \left(\int_{\Bbb R^d}|f_j(\mathbf{x})|^p\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}\right)^{1/p} \left(\int_{\Bbb R^d}|g(\mathbf{x})|^q\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}\right)^{1/q}\\&=\frac{1}{j^{\frac dp-s}}\left(\int_{\Bbb R^d}|f(\mathbf{x})|^p\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}\right)^{1/p} \left(\int_{\Bbb R^d}|g(\mathbf{x})|^q\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}\right)^{1/q} \\&=\frac{1}{j^{\frac dp-s}}\|f\|_{p}\|f\|_{q}\end{align}

If I suppose that, $\color{blue}{d>sp}$ then $\frac{1}{j^{\frac dp-s}}\to 0$
and the result follows.

> **Question:** How do I prove the case where $sp= d$?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is just a reminiscent of the this:
[How to prove that, $\lim\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\Bbb{R}} f_k(x) g(x) dm(x) = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2521555/how-to-prove-that-lim-limits-k-rightarrow-infty-int-bbbr-f-kx-gx/2521573#2521573).

If $sp =d$ then, Proceed as follows:

For,  $\varepsilon>0$ we know that there exist $g_\varepsilon\in C_c(\Bbb R)$ a continuous function of compact support such that,
$$ \|g-g_\varepsilon\|_q\le \varepsilon \|f\|_p^{-1} $$
and for this choice of $g_\varepsilon$ we can also find $f_\varepsilon\in C_c(\Bbb R)$  such that

$$ \|f-f_\varepsilon\|_p\le \varepsilon \|g_\varepsilon\|_q^{-1}$$

Proceeding [like here with](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2521573)   Cauchy Schwartz inequality replaced by Holder inequality, with $d=sp$, one easily arrives at

$$\left|\int_\mathbb R f_j(x) g(x) dx\right| \le\left[\varepsilon+\varepsilon j^{s-d}+ j^{s-d}\left|\int_{\text{supp }f_\varepsilon}f_\varepsilon(x) g_\varepsilon(\frac{x}{j}) dm(x)\right| \right]\\
= \left[\varepsilon+\varepsilon j^{s(1-p)}+ j^{s(1-p)}\left|\int_{\text{supp }f_\varepsilon}f_\varepsilon(x) g_\varepsilon(\frac{x}{j}) dm(x)\right| \right]$$

Moreover, $f_\varepsilon, g_\varepsilon$ are continuous functions  with compact support, we get
$$\color{blue}{\lim_{j\to \infty}\int_{\text{supp }f_\varepsilon}f_\varepsilon(x) g_\varepsilon(\frac{x}{j}) dx=\int_{\text{supp }f_\varepsilon}f_\varepsilon(x) g_\varepsilon(0) dx}$$

Whence,
$$ \limsup_{j\to \infty} \left|\int_\mathbb R f_j(x) g(x) dx\right| \\
\le \limsup_{j\to \infty} \left[\varepsilon+\varepsilon j^{s(1-p)}+ j^{s(1-p)}\left|\int_{\text{supp }f_\varepsilon}f_\varepsilon(x) g_\varepsilon(\frac{x}{j}) dm(x)\right| \right]=\varepsilon $$

Thus, for all $\varepsilon>0,$ we have, $$ \limsup_{j\to \infty} \left|\int_\mathbb R f_j(x) g(x) dx\right| \le \varepsilon $$
letting  $\varepsilon\to 0$  yields the require result.

$$ \color{red}{\lim_{j\to \infty}  \int_\mathbb R f_j(x) g(x) dx =0.} $$

Comment: You say a certain limit is less than $\epsilon$ at a point where we don't yet know the limit _exists_. Cleaner to say $\limsup<\epsilon$ for every $\epsilon>0$, hence $\lim=0$. (This is why, it seems to me, "$\limsup$" and "$\liminf$" exist - we can talk about them before we know anything about the existence of the limit.)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich   Which limit is uncertain? please I don't see it? Is that why you down voted? But do have this $$\lim_{j\to \infty}\int_{\text{supp }f_\varepsilon}f_\varepsilon(x) g_\varepsilon(\frac{x}{j}) dx=\int_{\text{supp }f_\varepsilon}f_\varepsilon(x) g_\varepsilon(0) dx$$ right?

Comment: ??? I don't see any downvotes. The problem I mention appears in a few places. For example, when you say $\lim_{j\to \infty} \left|\int_\mathbb R f_j(x) g(x) dx\right| \le \varepsilon$ we don't yet know that that limit exists.

Comment: In a logic sense you are right. It because the righ side. you should be a very strong as corrector teacher :) thanks you are fully right

Comment: I'm right "in a logic sense"? What other sense might be relevant? You can't talk about limits until you know they exist!

Comment: I am doing analysis. Any way wil you apply squeeze theorem? I think it is similar like here?

Comment: Of course it's the "squeeze theorem". That theorem doesn't allow you to talk about limits if you don't know they exist.

Comment: Say we know $\lim1/n=0$ and we want to use ST to show that $\lim1/(2n+1)=0$. A correct application of ST: "Since $0\le1/(2n+1)\le1/n$ and blah blah, $\lim1/(2n+1)=0$." Something reading "Since $0\le\lim1/(2n+1)\le\lim1/n$,..." is _not_ a correct application of ST.

Comment: Why does someone down vote this post?

Answer (score 0):

Note it's not true for $p=1$. Assume $p>1$. Come to think of it, it's also false for $p=\infty$. Assume $p<\infty$.

Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $A>0$ so that $$\left(\int_{|x|\le A}|g(x)|^q\right)^{1/q}<\epsilon.$$(This is where $q<\infty$ is needed.)
An explicit calculation shows that $$\left(\int_{|x|>A}|f_j(x)|^p\right)^{1/p}\to0.$$(This uses $p<\infty$.)

**Edit:** What's above will look like a solution to many readers. Others may be wondering how those two lines prove what's asserted. The (standard) argument goes like so: Assume $\epsilon$ and $A$ are as above. Choose $N$ so that $$\left(\int_{|x|>A}|f_j(x)|^p\right)^{1/p}<\epsilon\quad(j>N).$$
Noting that $||f_j||_p=||f||_p$ (since $sp=d$), for $j>N$ we have $$\left|\int f_jg\right|\le\left|\int_{|x\le A}f_jg\right|+\left|\int_{|x|>A}f_jg\right|\le||f||_p\epsilon+\epsilon||g||_q.$$

Comment: Sorry but I don't get the first inequality souldn't be $|x|>A$ as in the second case?

Comment: In fact your idea is $$\lim_{A\to \infty}\left(\int_{|x|> A}|g(x)|^q\right)^{1/q}=0$$

Comment: @GuyFsone No. See the edit - that may clarify things.

Comment: I have seen the edit. Also this is not true:$ ||f_j||_p=||f||_p$ , $f_j $ is not necessary  a mollifier

Comment: How do you obtain this: $$\lim_{A\to \infty}\left(\int_{|x|\le A}|g(x)|^q\right)^{1/q}=0$$

Comment: Sorry I don't how your convergence works out

Comment: The main point is to be able to prove that $$\left|\int_{|x|\le A}f_jg\right|\to 0$$ which I can find it out

Comment: I didn't say anything about mollifiers. The assumption that $sp=d$ shows that $||f_j||_p=||f||_p$. The fact that $\lim_{A\to0}\int_{|x|\le A}|g(x)|^p=0$ is clear from dominated convergence.

Comment: How the convergence works out: I've shown that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $N$ so that $|\int f_jg|<c\epsilon$ for every $j>N$. What more do you want?

Comment: It is clear now thtanks

Comment: alright it is ok now

Comment: One more utterly trivial detail that I left out: Why is $\lim_j\int_{|x|\ge A}|f_j|^p=0$? Since $sp=d$, it follows that $\int_{|x|\ge A}|f_j|^p=\int_{|x|\ge jA}|f|^p$, which tends to zero, again by dominated convergence.

Comment: @GuyFsone It's ok now? It was ok all along - I didn't make any changes. (Except for mentioning that $sp=d$, which _was_ already assumed in the _question_.)

Comment: Yes with your explanations I got it