# Is there an example of a function that is $L^{p_2}$ but not $L^{p_1}$ and not $L^{p_3}$?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, examples-counterexamples, lp-spaces

If $\Omega\subset\Bbb R$ is compact we have $L^{\infty}(\Omega)\subset L^p(\Omega)\subset L^q(\Omega)\subset L^1(\Omega)$ if $p>q$ but it is not true if $\Omega$ is not compact.

The function $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is in $L^p(1,\infty)\ \forall p>1$ but not in $L^1(1,\infty)$ with $\Omega=(1,\infty)$.

For some $p_1<p_2<p_3$ is there an example of a function that is $L^{p_2}$  but not $L^{p_1}$ and not $L^{p_3}$?

Comment: Yes, you can construct such examples in $L^p(\mathbb R)$. [Here's](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/805982/8157) some hints.

Comment: No, the function $1/x$ is _not_ in $L^p(0,1)$ for $p>1$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes I corrected it

Comment: You might find it interesting to show that $L^{p_2} \subset L^{p_1} \cap L^{p_3}$, i.e. if $f$ is $L^{p_1}$ and $L^{p_3}$ then it is necessarily $L^{p_2}$.

Comment: So it’s an equality $L^2=L^1\cap L^3$ and not a strict subset then?

Answer (score 3):

You could let $\Omega = (0,\infty)$ and define $$f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{cl} x^{-1/p_3} & 0 < x < 1 \\ x^{-1/p_1} & 1 \le x < \infty. \end{array} \right.$$